# 3D Multiview Rendering

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

I have the following scene (please see the image below) the right ball is hitting the middle cube which starts to roll and eventually hits the left cube. The depth information is important to me so I use two cameras with side angles to gain the depth of the objects as well. 
[image]

1) How is it possible to render both of the cameras to one output file? (if you have any other suggestions of how to get the depth of the object I would love to hear about it) 
2) If (1) is not possible how is it possible to render both of the cameras to two different files? 
3) How can I get the data of an object which wasn't animated? for example in the current scene, I want to know the location of the middle cube in each frame. How can I get JSON file (or any other format) with this data?

Setup:
Ubuntu 18.04
Blender 2.8

Thank you in advance,
Aviv

Comment: Are you wanting the to switch between cameras in the animation?

Comment: No @Millard I know how to switch between cameras I want to shot from two cameras at the same time and turn them into one output file.

Comment: Well, I don't think it's possible to render both cameras to one file, (I could be wrong) why do you need them on the same file?

Comment: In order to create stereo video and depth. Do you know how can I render both of the cameras to separate files?

Comment: If youre only interested in the distance of the camera to the center of the cube, you could use python to measure it like `(camera.location - object.location).length`.

Comment: No, I don't want to measure the location between the camera and an object.

Comment: No, I don't want to measure the location between the camera and an object. what I want to do is first record the scene from two cameras but receive one output video which is a combination of both of them (I think the professional term is stereoscopy video). I also want to write the location of the cube in each frame to a JSON file, how is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do that manually, blender already comes with a stereoscopic feature, I don't know much about it, so here's the page on the blender manual.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/multiview/usage.html#introduction

Comment: Thanks! I will look at it.
 I want to know the location of the middle cube in each frame. How can I get JSON file (or any other format) with this data?

Comment: I'm not even sure what a JSON file is, so I probably can't help you ;\

Answer (score 0):

What would probably work is copying the scene to a second scene and have a different camera selected in each of the scenes.
Then you can use the compositor to get views from both scenes (with two Input -> Render Layer Nodes) and transform them in such a way that your final image contains both views